# Rails: Using Ajax to fill Jquery Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, ajax

I've been all over the place plugging different things into this process and I still get no results.

Sometimes I get the infamous extra "<" error, sometimes absolutely nothing happens, and I'm not sure if this is the problem but I think Google developer is showing that the current page is being sent as the json file I'm asking for and not the json I'm sending (see later). This is what I see in google developer:
[image]
Which is definitly NOT my json file:
[image]
In any case, this is my javascript:

```
$('#q_name_cont').autocomplete({
url: "autocomplete/items",
dataType: 'json'
});
```

This is my route:

```
get 'autocomplete/items' => 'home#autocomplete_items', :defaults=>{:format=>'json'}
```

Controller Action (commented out part is another method I was trying for a while):

```
def autocomplete_items
  # respond_to do |format|
  # format.js {render 'autocomplete_items'}
@products = Item.all.order(:name)
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { 
    render json: @products.map {|item| item.name}
  }
end
end
```

Before I was using mapping, I was using this view for the render:

```
{
"items": [
<%Item.all.each do |i|%>
    { "<%=i.name%>","<%=i.name%>" },
<%#end%>
    { "value": "",        "data": "" }
]
}
```

I've really been all over the place, trying for a very long time to get this to work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, Your `url` and `dataType` options just do not exist in autocomplete's  documentation. You could try `source` option instead:

```
$('#q_name_cont').autocomplete({
  source: function (request, response) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/autocomplete/items", // should be with '/'
      dataType: 'json',
      data: { query: request.term },
      success: function(data) {
        // call response to return the result to autocomplete box
        response(data);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Of course, this is just for showing up all items, if you want to filter like real autocomplete box, you should modify controller to filter the result base on query:

```
def autocomplete_items
  @products = Item.all.order(:name)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { 
      render json: @products
                      .where('name ILIKE ?', "%#{params[:query]}%")
                      .pluck(:name)
    }
  end
end
```